# CPanel Database connection error

Tags: php, mysql, cpanel

I recently switched to CPanel, and ever since then, I've had issues. I'm having an issue connecting to a database. I created it in CPanel, with the hypothetical username `'root'` and password `'123'`. I have a file `/scripts/dbh.php` and a file `/index.php`. Here are the contents.

dbh.php:

```
<?php
// Database Handler
$db_name = 'hughchalmers';
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "123";
$table_name = 'accounts';
$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $db_name) or         die('Cannot connect to database. Contact an admin');
?>
```

(hughchalmers is a database, accounts is a table)
 
index.php:

```
<?php
include($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/memedictionary/scripts/header.php');
include($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']. '/memedictionary/scripts/dbh.php')
?>
<head>
<title>Login</title>
</head>
<body>

</body>
```

What's the issue here? It just dies with that message I set (Cannot connect to database. Contact an admin). Apologies, I'm very new to MySQL and CPanel

Comment: The fourth parameter is DB, not table.. Is `accounts` a db or table?

Comment: accounts is a table within a database. Edited question, still doesn't work.

Comment: Use the connection error function for more information. http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.connect-error.php

Answer (score 0):

Check your last parameter for mysqli_connect(). Looks like you're referring to a table when instead it must be the database name or is it just a variable name but you're passing a database name actually?